# Why is there no error comparing string with object that do not implement __toString?

Tags: php

I encountered a problem like this.

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public $f = 3;

//  public function __toString()
//  {
//      return 'test';
//  }
}

$foo = new Foo();

// do not implement __toString() -> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class Foo could not be converted to string
//$str = strval($foo);
//$str = (string)$foo;
//echo $foo . PHP_EOL;

// error not occurred... why?
if ($foo == "test") {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

What happened in the clause if($foo == "test")?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It thows an error when you use `echo $foo` because echo expects a String, PHP will try to convert `$foo` to a String and will thrown an error since it can't do it. In case of the if condition, PHP won't try to do convert anything, it just compare the value of `$foo` which is an object and the string "test" to see it equal.

Comment: So... that clause is always false? (Without __toString implementation, like (object) == (string) ?)

Comment: It should be, yes.